# How to play mp4 from url in cordova android application?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, video

trying to add a video player in my android application using cordova, jquery mobile and android.. how to play a mp4 video in android using cordova. Any answer will be  appreciated...

Comment: html 5 supports video player..check this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: [`<video>` HTML5 tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) perhaps?

Comment: its already done,  but not showing in emulator

Comment: i want to show my video in emulator or android device.!

Comment: better use your device..

Comment: it might not be dead simple (there are issues with cordova/html5/android/video) but you should provide more detail: what have you tried so far? do you want to stream the video or play a local version? If local: do you want to play it from your project folder (resources probably?) or do you want to download it and play it offline?

Comment: Want to play it from my project folder.. The video player works when running the index.html file in browser. But it didn"t worked on the emulator, only the skin of the player will be appear